# How do I run SIMTOWER on windows 10 home version 1511?

Tags: windows-10, emulator, disk-operating-system

I have my old disk for simtower and want to play it but all my pcs are windows 10 home (Version 1511 - OS Build 10586318)

[image: SYstem settings]

please help me download emulator and play. my user name does have a space in it. so when I type "mount c c:\users\catie bug\desktop\dosgames" it doesn't read the space.

Comment: Try putting the path in quotes.

Answer (score -1):

I would just change the name of the folder to the same, but with an underscore where the space now stands. Or even easier: I would make a folder on my root drive where I save the game in, so I don't have to type the whole path.

Comment: Renaming user profile directory will put stuff on fire. Not literally, but you get the idea. Folder in drive's root will probably have permission issues, would be nice if you could explain how to resolve them.